# Visual Studio Settings file - how does it work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, settings

I do not understand the following things:

1. What is the difference between app.config (applicationname.exe.config) and settings file ?
2. I am unable to locate the *.settings file in Windows7 AppData directory under the specific account (I heard that it should be located somewhere over there) ?
3. Let's assume that *.settings file is somewhere on the hard drive. Why on the development time the data from settings file are copied to application config file?

Kind Regards
PK

Answer (score 6):

So the **default settings** are stored in the `<exename>.config` file located in the same directory as the executable.

The reason you do cannot find the user.config file is it is only created if you have made changes to the defaults.  The user settings override the defaults which are stored in the `<exename>.config` file. **If no changes have been made, then no user configuration file will exist.**  And... once it does exist you will notice that only the settings which have been changes will show up in the user.config file.

To test this... create a dummy variable called like temp in your Settings file.  When you start your application do:

```
Settings1.Default.temp = Settings1.Default.temp + 1;
Settings1.Default.Save();
```

You will now have a file called user.config created in the user's ApplicationData folder which on Vista is in: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<company>\<productname>`

Here is some code I wrote to help identify where all the various SpecialFolders where on different Operating Systems. (Might want to do a find-replace for `log.Debug` and replace with `Console.WriteLine`)

```
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments ));
log.Debug("SpecialFolder.System: " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System ));
```

Output On Windows Server 2003:

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: "C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Application Data"
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data"
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: "C:\Program Files"
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: "C:\Program Files\Common Files"
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: "C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Desktop"
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: "C:\Documents and Settings\blake\Local Settings\Application Data"
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: "C:\Documents and Settings\blake\My Documents"
SpecialFolder.System: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
```

Output on Vista:

```
SpecialFolder.ApplicationData: "C:\Users\blake\AppData\Roaming"
SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData: "C:\ProgramData"
SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles: "C:\Program Files"
SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles: "C:\Program Files\Common Files"
SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory: "C:\Users\blake\Desktop"
SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData: "C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local"
SpecialFolder.MyDocuments: "C:\Users\blake\Documents"
SpecialFolder.System: "C:\Windows\system32"
```

Comment: Adding a small extra bit of info here. Since the question is about Visual Studio I thought it appropriate to mention that the "<company>" could be Microsoft_Corporation. So as an example, I just found settings for my current project in development here:

"C:\Users\tony\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\DefaultDomain_Url_o3ghzq4nzylalqdtx0msfcg4cilbn2mv\12.0.31101.0\user.config"

This is VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

1. The app.config file represents settings intrinsic to the application, and will apply to all sessions of the application. The *.settings file is typically for settings specific to a given user's use of an application.
2. Try looking in the Application Data directory beneath Local Settings [«username»\Local Settings\Application Data\«app name ...»], instead of the user's direct Application Data directory [«username»\Application Data].
3. The copy of the settings in the app.config file for a given *.settings file are used to initialize it the first time those settings are used; including the case when a new setting is added and a prior copy of the *.settings file doesn't have the new setting yet.

Here is a link for a brief walk-through of settings in C#.

[Using Settings in C# (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The problem is that settings file ain't there. There is no app directory under the: «username»\Local Settings\Application Data\ :/ I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Try «username»\AppData\Local instead. This folder may be hidden, but should exist anyways. You can unset hidden items in the view for explorer.

Comment: It is really not there! Do you know any tool which I can use to monitor where the exe file is reading from?

Comment: Is this possible that settings file would be embedded into the assembly itself?

Comment: Can you try opening up windows explorer and entering "shell:Local AppData" (without quotes) into the location/address? Where does it take you when you enter that path. Also, check for the company name you used to register your copy visual studio. By default, that company name will get written into your AssemblyInfo file and is used to scope the settings for applications you create.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. The settings file gets stored in user.config by default, not in a file named .settings . That might be throwing you off if you're looking for files with that extension.

Comment: In general, when looking for files whose whereabouts are not obvious, Everything Search Engine (http://www.voidtools.com) does a great job. Actually, it does a great job even if you already know where the file is (it's _that_ fast)

Comment: Check for setting's scope, if it is application wide then its read only and values will be picked-up from config file and no file will be created.