# Datasources in C#

Tags: c#, datasource

Long time reader, first time poster.

**Background:**

We have developed a small application in C# for creating proprietary binary files for use in our embedded system. The application is very simple, just a few textboxes, comboboxes and checkboxes, and a couple of buttons for creating files. It is distributed to our customers as just an .exe file, meaning, no installation is required, and that is how we want it.

**Problem:**

I have been tasked by our support staff to implement a way to save some settings and load them again. This data should be retained in between runs of the app. The user should be able to save a couple of these under different names.

**The question is:**

What are my options? So far I have identified 3 possible solutions:

- Plain text files: Cumbersome to work with
- Settings file: Visual Studio can use a settings file as a datasource, I have tried this approach, but is stuck. Perhaps not for me?
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact: I know very little of this. Can we use our deployment method with this solution?

Comment: What problem have you seen with using the settings file?  Where have you become stuck?

Comment: The problem with Settings is that i have only one! I want to let the user create a couple of configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an **Xml file** to save your settings. Your **application** could load these settings and act accordingly. If you are .Net 4.0, you could **LINQ** that will make your job pretty easy. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302158.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the data to be saved is small and simple, then I would go for physical files; the overhead in setting up the SQL Server Compact for you application is larger than just serialising a class or struct to XML and saving to file.

On the other hand, if the data becomes more complicated, including one-to-many or many-to-many style of relationship, then you would want to move to the database solution.

To keep flexibility ensure you decouple the save/load code so you can change from file to database if the need arises.

Comment: Aah yes. Why didn't i think of serializing to XML.  You verified what I thought, that going with a database would be too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

"C# Settings" should work for you.  Have you tried it right? 
Please see the below links.  Hope it helps

[Visual Studio Settings file - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001487/visual-studio-settings-file-how-does-it-work)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx

It worked for me.

Comment: Settings if fine if you just have one dataset. I wish to create a couple of them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use user or application settings

Add an app.config file to your project and edit the settings like this

```
<setting name="Setting" serializeAs="String">
   <value>This is the setting value</value>
</setting>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx#settingscs_topic2

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have created a small "settings" class.
I have then over ridden the ToString method and also created a parse method.

I have stored each setting in the settings file using a global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection type to store a collection of settings.  I use the ToString method to store the setting and the Parse method to read it back in.

Lastly, I use an int type to store the currently selected index.