# how to change settings without app.config devexpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, app-config, xaf

I need app.config automatically database informations setting according to a user control ..
Normally, we are setting up database informations in app.config. But when standart users run this program, it must login database setting on a interface . so, they should enter their database informations . not in app.config.
how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using visual studio for Windows Form Application then you can create `Settings` to store your different type of values in it. You can write and read settings programmatically like this.

```
//To Write
Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName = textBox1.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

//To Read
textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;
```

You can find article about User's Settings on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edited**
Full Example given here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/create-single-connection-string-for-all-windows-form-in-net/

Comment: i'm using winform in Visual Studio..Why should am i seetings folder in visual studio? and where should i use your codes in project?

Comment: If you would not like to store your settings in database and want to make it user independently then you can use `Properties.Settings` feature in Windows Form Application. Generally the default settings are stored in `<exename>.config` file in same folder location where aplicatin has installed. But, once you make any change in the setting file you the another copy will be created in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<company>\<productname>` folder with changes. Read more about setting file location [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016530/3761928)

Comment: You can create another windows form to assign settings for it.. You need to place some controls on windows form and a button to save that settings. you can only change the value of settings at runtime.. you cannot create new. To create new setting you have to use `Project Properties->Settings` window.

Comment: i'm develope new version this project. Now, users must change app.config database informations according to their pc features. So i need a interface and some features on interface and here must do app.config settings. Actually i won't create  user database informations.. They will enter their informations after application will start and connection database..Only i want to do it..

Comment: That's what i am trying to say that.. you can use `Settings` to store database connection info. for example: Server Name, Database Name, User ID, Password, etc. then you can configure connection string using those information from Setting Class. Look at these articles [Link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18558/Encrypting-windows-application-connection-strings), [Link2](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/573744-where-store-database-connection-string-info-windows-forms-application)

Comment: i tried your said and examined your links.. Textbox in winform i can appearence appconfig connection string info.. But i want to edit this informations and click button then  connection string in app.config file can update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing using DevExpress XAF, you can display a standard Windows form just before the application startup. Technically, this form can be invoked via the ShowDialog method before the winApplication.Setup() call in the Main routine (of course, the invocation must be done only if no user settings are saved yet). Once you display this dialog and gather user input, update the winApplication.ConnectionString property accordingly ([see also](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3155)).
Another more complex solution is to embed this database settings UI into the logon form as described at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1344.
Do not hesitate to [contact the DevExpress support team](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) if you want to further discuss the implementation of this task.

Comment: actually, i try to do this for a long time. )i follow this arctiect : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2982 and i examined your link before very long time.) firstly my purpose, i bring  fields(server name, database name, user, password) in log on window. These fields appearence now. But when i entered texts in these textbox and pressed logon, i saw exception. This exception security strategy complex's properties user type and role type. In my sending link this explained. I changed path according to my project but still i saw exception.

Comment: My project some complex does not look like the example in the link for example which including Employee.cs and i don't know adding this authentication properties add this class.

Comment: My problem including exceptions and define different  very get set objects so i don't ask support team. no longer i don't know how i tell my problem.. :/

Comment: i have log in window username and password and there are must be. I already have a user name and password entry screen does not turn on without a project where I'll use for the config settings?